# How to access context variable inside Airflow Kubernetes Pod Operator?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

Need to know how to access context variable from Kubernetes Pod Operator. I can see it's possible from PythonOperator but I am not sure how to do that in Kubernetes Pod Operator.

For example, I want to access the 'execution date' variable. I do not want to use any macros for this.

Comment: I think `{{ ds }}` may help in this case. 
You can find example usage of `{{ ds }}` [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/using-kubernetes-pod-operator#kubernetespodoperator_configuration) - see `arguments=['{{ ds }}']`.

Does this answer your question ?

Comment: Yes. I actually did that. Just found out that they have a bug in template variables for Kubernetes pod operator in 2.0.0.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13522

@matt_j